Not getting any responce from server Express.js
I am trying to make a POST request to my server with port 5000. But not getting any response. My server is running but not getting any response.
Here is my app.js file
import express from "express";
import cors from "cors";
import dotenv from "dotenv";
import { dbConnection } from "./database/dbConnection.js";
import reservationRouter from "./routes/reservationRoute.js";
import { errorMiddleware } from "./error/error.js";

const app = express();
dotenv.config({ path: "./config/config.env" });

app.use(
  cors({
    origin: [process.env.FRONTEND_URL],
    methods: ["POST"],
    credentials: true,
  })
);

app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use("/api/v1/reservation", reservationRouter);

dbConnection();

app.use(errorMiddleware);

export default app;

Here is my server.js file
import app from "./app.js";

app.listen(process.env.PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Server running at port ${process.env.PORT}`);
});

Also here is my reservationRoute.js
import express from "express";
import { sendReservation } from "../controller/reservation.js";

const router = express.Router();

router.route("/send").post(sendReservation);

export default router;


Here is the sendReservation function
import ErrorHandler from "../error/error.js";
import { Reservation } from "../models/reservationSchema.js";

const sendReservation = async (req, res, next) => {
  console.log("Received reservation request:", req.body);
  const { firstName, lastName, email, phone, date, time } = req.body;

  if (!firstName || !lastName || !email || !phone || !date || !time) {
    console.log("Missing fields in the request");
    return new ErrorHandler("Please fill the form completely to proceed", 400);
  }

  try {
    const newReservation = { firstName, lastName, email, phone, date, time };
    console.log("Creating new reservation:", newReservation);
    await Reservation.create(newReservation);
    console.log("Reservation created successfully");
    res.status(201).json({
      status: "success",
      message: "Reservation created successfully",
    });
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error creating reservation:", error);
    if (error.name === "ValidationError") {
      const validationErrors = Object.values(error.errors).map(
        (err) => err.message
      );
      return next(new ErrorHandler(validationErrors.join(" , "), 400));
    }

    // Handle other errors
    return next(error);
  }
};

export default sendReservation;

Here is dbConnection
import mongoose from "mongoose";

export const dbConnection = () => {
  mongoose
    .connect(process.env.MONGO_URI, {
      dbName: "Restaurant MERN Stack Project",
    })
    .then(() => {
      console.log("Connected to Database successfully ");
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log(error);
    });
};

Can anyone please help me to solve my problem
Here is some screenshot of my error
Server Connected Successfully
and No response from Server

Where's the code for sendReservation()?  If the client connects to /api/v1/reservation, but you never get a response back, then that's probably because sendReservation() never sends a response.  Also, please show exactly what is making the POST so we can see the particulars of the request.

If the POST is coming from a browser, did you look in the network tab of the Chrome inspector to see exactly what is being sent and received back?

can you send the implementation of sendReservation, and dbConnection those two can be possible suspects

also your errorMiddleware may also not be calling next

I tried emulating the same as your code locally, and there seems to be no problem, what I did was remove the suspect parts I mentioned earlier in this comment thread. Then I just made a simple implementatino of the sendReservation by giving it basic (req,res) => res.send({success:true}) just to test.

Here check I have given the sendReservation function. Can you find any error

Can anyone help me with the problem as I am not able to get the error.

I now understood the error. In my code there was a simple mistake at this part
if (!firstName || !lastName || !email || !phone || !date || !time) {
    console.log("Missing fields in the request");
    //check point 1
    return new ErrorHandler("Please fill the form completely to proceed", 400);
  }

instead it should be
if (!firstName || !lastName || !email || !phone || !date || !time) {
    console.log("Missing fields in the request");
    //check point 1
    return next(new ErrorHandler("Please fill the form completely to proceed", 400));
    //     ^^^^ needed to add this
  }


The issue for no response is that the response is not being returned by the route handler. The potential code for this issue has been commented below as  check point 1. Please check it. Another possibility is that the custom error handling middleware has a no response coded in it. Please check this as well.
const sendReservation = async (req, res, next) => {
  console.log("Received reservation request:", req.body);
  const { firstName, lastName, email, phone, date, time } = req.body;

  if (!firstName || !lastName || !email || !phone || !date || !time) {
    console.log("Missing fields in the request");
    //check point 1
    return new ErrorHandler("Please fill the form completely to proceed", 400);
  }

  try {
    const newReservation = { firstName, lastName, email, phone, date, time };
    console.log("Creating new reservation:", newReservation);
    await Reservation.create(newReservation);
    console.log("Reservation created successfully");
    res.status(201).json({
      status: "success",
      message: "Reservation created successfully",
    });
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error creating reservation:", error);
    if (error.name === "ValidationError") {
      const validationErrors = Object.values(error.errors).map(
        (err) => err.message
      );
      return next(new ErrorHandler(validationErrors.join(" , "), 400));
    }

    // Handle other errors
    return next(error);
  }
};

